# C#: What does it mean to use a variable like a type?

Tags: c#, types

I'm new to C#, coming from a Javascript background (so 'typing' is quite new to me).

What does the warning "... is a variable but is used like a type" mean?

I have the following code within a static function called `test`:

```
var activeCell = new ExcelReference(1, 1);
Type type = typeof(activeCell);
```

Comment: `Type type = typeof(ExcelReference)` or `Type type = activeCell.GetType();`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `typeof` only with a type, for example `Type type = typeof(ExcelReference);`

If you want to know what type is this variable use `Type type = activeCell.GetType();`

Comment: Thank you. When would you use `typeof()` There's another answer on this page that mentions reflection - it seems this method would only be useful if I were making use of reflection?

Comment: @ZachSmith Also you can, for example, check input type of parameter `if(input.GetType() == typeof(string)) {...}`. in this example `input` is of type `object`. This is not reflection, this is type generalization.

Comment: i see, thank you. In JS you would say `if (typeof input === 'string') {...}`

Comment: @ZachSmith Yes, but in c# `input` should be derived from general base type (object). Also there is "like-JS" type `dynamic`. But it is slow and not recomended for common using.

Answer (score 2):

Quite easy in fact.
**typeof** is used with a Class, Interface etc name, meanwhile for what you want you will need the **GetType** function.

Example :

```
public class MyObject
{
    public static Type GetMyObjectClassType()
    {
        return typeof(MyObject);
    }
    public static Type GetMyObjectInstanceType(MyObject someObject)
    {
        return someObject.GetType();
    }

    public static Type GetAnyClassType<GenericClass>()
    {
        return typeof(GenericClass);
    }
    public static Type GetAnyObjectInstanceType(object someObject)
    {
        return someObject.GetType();
    }

    public void Demo()
    {
        var someObject = new MyObject();
        Console.WriteLine(GetMyObjectClassType()); // will write the type of the class MyObject
        Console.WriteLine(GetMyObjectInstanceType(someObject)); // will write the type of your instance of MyObject called someObject
        Console.WriteLine(GetAnyClassType<MyObject>()); // will write the type of any given class, here MyObject
        Console.WriteLine(GetAnyClassType<System.Windows.Application>()); //  will write the type of any given class, here System.Windows.Application
        Console.WriteLine(GetAnyObjectInstanceType("test")); // will write the type of any given instance, here some string called "test"
        Console.WriteLine(GetAnyObjectInstanceType(someObject)); // will write the type of any given instance, here your instance of MyObject called someObject
    }
}
```